# Window can't handle routed events raised from within a descendants Initialized event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a MainWindow that's already displayed to the user. Within that window is a button that, when clicked, loads a UserControl consisting of a ListBox containing TextBlocks. These TextBlocks raise a routed event (i.e. SomeEvent) within event handlers for their Initialized and Loaded events. However, only the events raised on TextBlock.Loaded appear to bubble up the visual tree to the MainWindow, while the events raised on TextBlock.Initialized do not.

Consider the following sample project:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="RoutedEventsExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ui_mainWindowLoadStatus" />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Items Initialized:" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ui_initializedCount" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Items Loaded:" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ui_loadedCount" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Click="Button_OnClick" Content="Display Items" Margin="0,20,0,0" />

        <Border x:Name="ui_host" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int m_initializedCount;
    private int m_loadedCount;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        AddHandler(SomeEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource.ToString().Contains("Initialized"))
            {
                ui_initializedCount.Text = Convert.ToString(++m_initializedCount);
            }
            else if (e.OriginalSource.ToString().Contains("Loaded"))
            {
                ui_loadedCount.Text = Convert.ToString(++m_loadedCount);
            }
        }));

        Loaded += (s, e) => ui_mainWindowLoadStatus.Text = "MainWindow.IsLoaded = " + IsLoaded;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ui_host.Child = new Items();
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent SomeEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Some", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

**Items.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="RoutedEventsExample.Items"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:routedEventsExample="clr-namespace:RoutedEventsExample"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type routedEventsExample:Items}}, Path=ItemsSource}"
             VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                <routedEventsExample:Item />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

**Items.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Items : UserControl
{
    private const int NumberOfItems = 3;

    public IEnumerable<string> ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            var itemsSource = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 1; i <= NumberOfItems; i++)
            {
                itemsSource.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
            }

            return itemsSource;
        }
    }

    public Items()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Item.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="RoutedEventsExample.Item"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance system:String}">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Initialized="TextBlock_OnInitialized" Loaded="TextBlock_OnLoaded" />
</UserControl>
```

**Item.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Item : UserControl
{
    public Item()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBlock_OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
        textBlock.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.SomeEvent, "TextBlock_OnInitialized: " + textBlock.Text));
    }

    private void TextBlock_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
        textBlock.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.SomeEvent, "TextBlock_OnLoaded: " + textBlock.Text));
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why the "Some" events raised from the TextBlock's Initialized handler do NOT get handled by the MainWindow, while the "Some" events raised from the TextBlock's Loaded handler DO get handled by the MainWindow?